# Function is passing previous values of a variable instead of the present one in Unity3D

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing an application where in the user can view all the products, can view a single product and can download a specific product.

This is my code:

```
IEnumerator ButtonClicked(int num, string name, string url, string color, string size, string price, string description)
{
    prodName.text = name.ToString ();
    prodColor.text = color.ToString ();
    prodSize.text = size.ToString ();
    prodPrice.text = price.ToString ();
    prodDesc.text = description.ToString ();

    string Url = url; 
    WWW www = new WWW (Url);
    yield return www;
    Texture2D texture = www.texture;

    Image img = prodImg.GetComponent<Image> ();
    img.sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);

    string name2 = name.ToString ();
    Debug.Log (name2.ToString ());
    downloadButton.onClick.AddListener (() => StartCoroutine (onDownloadClick (name2.ToString ())));

}


IEnumerator onDownloadClick(string name) {

    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection (conn)) {
        dbConnection.Open ();
        using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand ()) {
            string sqlQuery = String.Format ("INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(Name) VALUES(\"{0}\")", name); 
            dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            dbCmd.ExecuteScalar ();
            dbConnection.Close ();
        }


    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (.1f);
    Debug.Log (name.ToString ());

}
```

On the ButtonClicked function, it returns only one value but when the onDownloadClick function, the present value and all the previous value is showing. What seems to be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what your problem is but I recommend you read & understand the [basic data types in C#](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm). *My eyes were bleeding when I saw you converting `string` to `string` which is totally unnecessary. You did this **8** times in that tiny `ButtonClicked` function.* This is what happens when you use the `ToString ()` function. Don't call `ToString ()` on a `string` type.

Comment: When is ButtonClicked executed? Every time you run ButtonClicked a listener to onDownloadClick with that name. I'm guessing you click the button then change value then download, which would give you the name of the last time you executed ButtonClicked as the download value.

Comment: So to fix this, you should only execute addListener once and get the prodName.text in the download method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button.onClick` is a `ButtonClickedEvent` which will hold "listeners" and then invokes them whenever it's told to (ie. when the owning `UnityEngine.UI.Button` is clicked).  The list of "listeners" will build up if you never unsubscribe them; you're only adding to the list via `AddListener`:

```
downloadButton.onClick.AddListener (() => StartCoroutine (onDownloadClick (name2.ToString ())));
```

Try clearing the `ButtonClickedEvent` object before adding a new listener like this:

```
downloadButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
downloadButton.onClick.AddListener (() => StartCoroutine (onDownloadClick (name2.ToString ())));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sarah Happy to help.  If this solved your issue you can select it as the answer so the question is marked as resolved.